# Couldn't find User with id=update_password with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes

I'm using devise on a Rails application and for various reasons I needed to add a custom password change, using solution 3 from here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password

I've looked through various other questions and tried augmenting my routes in a number of ways but the url always comes up /users/update_password (without a parameter passed), or /users/update_password.254 (with a parameter passed). I need it to be /users/254/update_password.

Here is the Users Controller I'm working with (relevant methods are update_password and user_params).

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
inherit_resources
load_and_authorize_resource
before_filter :authenticate_user!

def destroy
  name = @user.to_s
  destroy!(notice: "User #{@user.to_s} was deleted.")
end

def edit
  @user = current_user
end

def update_password
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  if @user.update_with_password(user_params)
    sign_in @user, :bypass => true
    redirect_to root_path
  else
     render "edit"
 end
end

private

def build_resource_params
  [params.fetch(:user, {}).permit(:name, :email, :phone_number, :password, :password_confirmation).tap do |p|
    p[:institution_pid] = build_institution_pid if params[:user][:institution_pid]
    p[:role_ids] = build_role_ids if params[:user][:role_ids]
  end]
end

def build_institution_pid
  institution = Institution.find(params[:user][:institution_pid])
  authorize!(:add_user, institution)
  institution.id
end

def build_role_ids
  [].tap do |role_ids|
    roles = Role.find(params[:user][:role_ids].reject &:blank?)
    roles.each do |role|
      authorize!(:add_user, role)
      role_ids << role.id
    end
  end
end

def user_params
  params.required(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
end

end
```

This is the relevant portion of routes.rb

```
devise_for :users

resources :users do
  collection do
    get 'password'
    put 'update_password'
  end
end
```

This is the view I created to go with it:

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Change Password</h1>
</div>

<%= form_for(@user, :url => { :action => "update_password" } ) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password, "Password" %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off"  %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :current_password %>
</div>
<div class="action_container">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

And this is the link: (currently with a parameter but I've tried without as well)

```
<li><%= link_to "Change Password", update_password_users_path(current_user) %></li>
```

When I click that link I get routed to a page that says ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show, Couldn't find User with id=update_password.

I tried to follow the instructions pretty closely and I've tried to fiddle with the routes a couple times to get it to work and I'm pretty lost at this point. Has anyone seen this before and can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you need, you will have the following routes:

```
resources :users do
  patch 'update_password', on: :collection
  get 'edit_password', on: :member
end
```

Then you'll add a link that would lead user to `update password form`. The link should look like as follows:

```
<li><%= link_to "Change Password", edit_password_user_path(current_user) %></li>
```

The link would lead to `users/edit_password.html.erb`:

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Change Password</h1>
</div>

<%= form_for(@user, :url => { :action => "update_password" } ) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password, "Password" %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off"  %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :current_password %>
</div>
<div class="action_container">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

When form is submitted, that would trigger `update_password` in `UsersController`. Here is the code for controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def edit_password
        @user = current_user
    end


    def update_password
        @user = User.find(current_user.id)
        if @user.update_with_password(user_params)
            sign_in @user, :bypass => true
            redirect_to root_url
        else
            render "edit_password"
        end
    end

    private

    def user_params
        params.required(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
    end

end
```

Comment: Okay, I think that helped but I'm now getting the error "ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#update_password,
param not found: user". It says it's coming from my user_params method. Thoughts?

Comment: If you would like to have `user_id` and have url as `/users/254/update_password`, you should add routes `get 'password'` and `put 'update_password'` on `memeber`, not on `collection`. I've updated my answer to show how it should look like.

Comment: That gave me this: NoMethodError in Institutions#show; line #29 raised undefined method `update_password_users_path'.

Comment: Wait, that was my fault. I had a typo. Okay, so now the url is fixed but it's the same error as before I switched from collection to member. Parameter missing, param not found: user.

Comment: Could you, please, clarify: the link we are talking about, is it the one that would lead to a form where user updates his password? What is the route for it?

Comment: Yeah, I put the code up for the form in my initial question. The route is supposed to be to users/:id/update_password and lead to a form that will allow the user to update their password. The URL is showing up in that format now but it gives me an error message. The full error is in my first comment.

Comment: I've changed my response to answer your question more specifically.

Comment: I actually already have another form under users/edit.html.erb. The update password form is at users/update_password.html.erb. Can you show me where to change the routes so that it links there?

Comment: You should change `get 'update_password', to: "users#edit"`. Say, if you have `modify_password` action in `UsersController`, then it would be `get 'modify_password', to: "users#modify_password"`

Comment: I tried changing the member route `get 'update_password', to: "users#update_password"` and that didn't work.

Comment: That's because `update_password` action in UsersController is for submitting the form. There are two stages: edit (when user clicks the link to change password) and update (when he actually changes password by submitting the form). `update_password` is for second. You should choose a name for the first.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just still not understanding what names exactly I should change and where. Would you mind terribly updating your answer so I can see it?

Comment: I've updated my answer as if I used `edit_password` for controller action (stage 1).

Comment: Okay, that gets me to the form. When I try to change the password though and submit I get this: `No route matches [PATCH] "/users/254/edit_password"`

Comment: I went ahead and changed the link to look like: `<%= link_to "Change Password", edit_password_user_path(current_user), method: :get %>` and that didn't make a difference.

Comment: I forgot to change the form action. Thank you so much for your help. It works now!!